# Noetic on Jammy?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are there any known downsides of  using the packages hosted at https://packages.ubuntu.com/, vs. those at http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu?

Some background:
Noetic is only supported on Ubuntu Focal, by design. We'd *like* to run Noetic on Jammy.

I notice that https://packages.ubuntu.com/ hosts a bunch of apt packages like [jammy/ros-desktop-full](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ros-desktop-full). I've installed that package into a container, and it seems to work fine (`roscore` starts, anyway). I'm surprised that I have never seen anyone suggest simply installing the Ubuntu metapackages (which *seems* much simpler).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400202/noetic-on-jammy?/) by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 567 on 2022-05-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2022-05-07**:
See also #q399664 - I should update my answer there but what I've seen since is that `ros-desktop-full` and related works well- I've gone well beyond just running roscore but no serious stress tests yet.  But it is missing a lot of standard stuff, some packages weren't ready in time for 22.04 (maybe 22.04.x will have them)- and a lot else isn't even in debian testing/unstable yet, so those require compiling, many packages require fixes to compile (mostly small ones, `boost::placeholders::_1` comes up a lot)- which then ought to get upstreamed into noetic sources or land in ros-o and eventually may become available in 22.04 apt packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I'm surprised that I have never seen anyone suggest simply installing the Ubuntu metapackages (which seems much simpler).

Because of [wiki/UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).

And see also [“upstream packages” increasingly becoming a problem](https://discourse.ros.org/t/upstream-packages-increasingly-becoming-a-problem/10902) on ROS Discourse.

> We'd *like* to run Noetic on Jammy.

The official recommendation for this sort of scenario (ie: running ROS on an unsupported OS) would be to use Docker. Or build from source.

Unofficially, there is an effort ongoing to enable building Noetic on `> Ubuntu 20.04`: [ros-o](https://github.com/ros-o). This does not provide binary packages, so you'd have to build from source for now.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-05-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rick Armstrong](https://answers.ros.org/users/13391/rick-armstrong/) on 2022-05-07**:
Thanks for taking the time to answer; there's a great deal of information there to help us keep from "stepping in it". BTW, I *think* our motivation for attempting to run on Jammy is so that we can use Python 3.10. At first blush, I thought "sure, why not?", but I will now circle-back and really understand what we're trying to achieve.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-07**:
Just to make sure: I merely answered your question as to why these packages aren't *recommended* more (often).

You could have legitimate reasons for wanting to use them. That would be something else.

re: Python 3.10: that should be possible if you build things from source. Success would depend on whether Python 3.10 has deprecated (or finally removed) certain things.

Again: I'm not telling you *not* to use the upstream packages, but I feel you need to be aware of the pros-and-cons before concluding "`roscore` started, so it seems they work".